# how to handle errors using $RESOURCE in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

i am trying to handle the "server side error codes" in angularjs like this but it is not working `$timeout(function() {
             $scope.register.sales_total_amount=data2;
           salesregister.save($scope.register,
               function(data){
                  data1=data.sales_id;
                              },
               function(error,status){
                      if(error.status===404)
                        {
                             alert("DATA CANNOT BE INSERTED PLEASE CHECK YOUR VALUES!!!!");
                        }
                                    }
                             );
           }, 2000);`

how can i handle the these server side errors???

Comment: Why are using the $timeout wrapping and what problem are you facing handling server errors in error callback?

Comment: i have used $timeout because i am making couple of API calls to make sure that they will execute in a queue one by one, and i am trying to print a simple message on the error code of 404 as written in code but its not working even though i am getting the  error code 404 from server.

Comment: The server should return http status codes in 4xx or 5xx range to hit the error callback.

Comment: i know that sir but the above shown code is not working is there any other way to handle the errors or am i doing it in a right way ?

Comment: In the browser console log see what http status code is returned? Is it 4xx or 5xx?

Comment: 400 is the returned error code this is the message from server( POST http://localhost:8088/rest/daybook/sales_registertest/?app_name=DAYBOOK_NEW&fields=* 400 (Bad  Request))

Comment: And you are checking for 404?